# ActiveRecord, has_many :through, but only on newest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

So I have the following (simplified) schema

User has many subscriptions
Subscriptions have a start and stop (dates), and references (belongs_to)  a publication
Publications have an id and a name
User has_many publications through subscriptions

A user may have multiple subscriptions to a publication, with different dates.

What I'd like is to get a list of the subscriptions for a user, but only the most recent, not in the future one, for each pub.

So given the following rows in subscriptions:

```
ID | user_id | start      | stop      | publication_id
1  | 1       | 2013-01-01 | 2013-12-01| 1
2  | 1       | 2014-01-01 | 2014-12-31| 1
3  | 1       | 2011-01-01 | 2011-12-31| 1
4  | 1       | 2013-01-01 | 2013-02-01| 2
```

The objects reprenting IDs 1 and 4 would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

In your User model

```
def current_subscriptions
  self.subscriptions.where("start < ? AND stop >= ?", Date.today, Date.today)
end
```

So for whatever @user.current_subscriptions, it would query their subscriptions for any that started before today and don't stop till today or after, which would remove objects with IDs 2 and 3 and return objects with IDs 1 and 4.

Also, include [Active Support](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) in your User model if you want to use Date.today to represent today's day